# Configuring MySQL with python on OS X lion

Tags: python, mysql, macos

MySQL is installed at /usr/local/mysql

In site.cfg the path for mysql_config is /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

but when i try to build in the terminal im getting this error:

hammads-imac-2:MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 syedhammad$ sudo python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'beta',4) -D_*version*_=1.2.4b4 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Wno-null-conversion -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
unable to execute clang: No such file or directory
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

Help Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need Xcode's Command Line Tools.

Download the lastest version of Xcode, then go to "Preferences", select "Download" tab, then install Command Line Tools.